# Diferencias entre cerrar un programa manualmente y usar "taskkill"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Cuando cierro spotify dando ALT+F4, con la crucecita de arriba a la derecha o incluso desde finalizar tarea en el administrador de tareas se me guarda el estado de la canción en la que estaba ("el tiempo"). Sin embargo al usar

```
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM spotify.exe")
subprocess.Popen("C:/Users/usuario/AppData/Roaming/Spotify/Spotify.exe")
```

Spotify se cierra de tal forma que no se guarda la canción en la que estaba ni en el minuto en el que estaba.

Por que ocurre esto? Hay alguna manera de cerrar el programa de forma que se guarde el estado de la cancion? Usando un comando de python.

```
os.system("TASKKILL /IM spotify.exe")
```

tampoco guarda el estado.

Comment: Prueba sin usar el parámetro `/F` (que no fuerza el kill, solo envía señal de cierre) a ver como funciona. Tienes que tener claro que las formas en que cierras la aplicación que has comentado al principio, son formas controladas por la propia aplicación, es decir, que la propia app "sabe" que le pidieron que se cierre e implementa el guardado del playlist. El `taskill` es el envío de una señal de cierre a la app, por fuera de la interfaz de usuario, posiblemente la app no tenga controlada este evento.

Comment: Ahh, y de paso: Bienvenido iozalla a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..